# Thinktecture IdentityServer self-service user creation

Tags: thinktecture-ident-server

We currently have several web systems that are using the old Membership provider in silos. I am looking at implementing a new server for identity management and discovered IdentityServer. Is it possible for a user to self-create an identity out of the box? Otherwise, are there add-ons or code samples that would assist in doing something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Identity Server can work with any user store, however only ASP.NET Identity and MembershipReboot is supported out-of-the-box.

If you want to implement your own user store to work with Identity Server, you can implement Identity Server's [IUserService](http://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docs/advanced/userService.html) interface to abstract it out.

Identity Server itself is not an identity manager but instead an OpenID Connect provider that handles Authentication and Authorization using the OpenID Connect 1.0 and OAuth 2.0 protocols. See my [blog post](https://www.scottbrady91.com/Identity-Server/Thinktecture-Identity-Server-3) for a brief overview or the [big picture](http://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docs/overview/bigPicture.html) section of the official documentation.

I started off in the same situation as you and ended up implementing Identity Server and migrating our user data from ASP.NET Membership to ASP.NET Identity. I would recommend the same for you.

Comment: I am also looking to move from ASP.NET Membership to ASP.NET Identity, so I think I get that. However, Identity Server displays a login view. I would like to customize/override that view so I can link to a self-registration view, which I would think would live within the Identity Server ASP.Net host application. If this isn't available out of the box, then I am wondering if there are add-ons/samples that would help me along instead of starting from scratch.

Comment: Yes, the login view lives within Identity Server. You can customize this or replace it using their [IViewService](http://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docs/advanced/customizingViews.html) interface. A combination of this and IUserService will allow you to have your login and registration within Identity Server.